# Implicit styles not working in SciCharts WPF?

Tags: wpf, scichart

I'm trying to set some implicit styles on the AxisPane of SciCharts -- just even to change a background color, ala:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type SciCharts:AxisPanel}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
</Style>
```

I've tried placing the style in the Application.Resources, inside the SciChartSurface.Resources, in a UserControl.Resources, and have had absolutely no luck.

Comment: Short answer: No. Implicit styles are not applied to AxisPanels.

Comment: I'm realizing that it looks like I have to work around some of the different parts of the Styling to get to what I want.  Frustrating, but possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that the AxisPanel was missing DefaultStyleKey and because of various properties set by default in the template, implicit styles were not applying.

We have added a property to AxisBase called AxisPanelStyle. This lets you apply a style directly to the axis panel via the parent axis:

```
 <s:SciChartSurface>
      <s:SciChartSurface.XAxis>
           <s:NumericAxis AxisPanelStyle="{StaticResource AStyleWithTargetTypeAxisPanel}"/>              
      </s:SciChartSurface.XAxis>
 </s:SciChartSurface>
```

This change has been committed to v5.1.0.11306 of scichart and pushed to nightly build shortly.

Best regards, 
Andrew

[SciChart tech lead]

Comment: That was fast!  Thank you.